# Typhoeus always receive error 401

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I want to make a get request to a url, so to do this I am using Typhoeus gem.

Code example:

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.get("https://url.com", userpwd: "user\name:pass#rd")
puts request.code
```

but I always receive code 401. Why ? When I put the url in my browser and insert domain username and password works.

Comment: Try to add a parameter `, followlocation: true`, and, optionall `, verbose: true` to see what actually happens.

Comment: Did you really mean to have a newline in the username?

Comment: I receive the same message error :/ my username is the string 'user\name' @mudasobwa

Comment: "user\\name:pass#rd" is equal to 'user\name:pass#rd', that's because `\n` is escaped to newline so to have a backslash it should be escaped "\\" (or replace double quotes with single ones)

Comment: anyway if the url was wrong it should be 404 not 401 !!